# pngfix on background images disable text selection and input elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6, pngfix

I am using [pngfix](http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/) in ie6. Images structure is the folowing: background image / transparent pngfixed image / text and input elements (all superposed). With pngfix, the text cannot be selected properly and input elements and submit buttons cannot be used at all.

I am using jquery 1.4.4. I have tried 1.3.2 and the problem is the same.
I have tried to set background images as relative with z-indexes lower than text, but it doesn't fix the problem.
Do you have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: If you can't reproduce the bug, tell me and i make a online reproduction of it.

Comment: You should make that online reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

PNGFix works by using a DirectX filter, which isn't selectable. I can only recommend that you do not use PNGfix on interactive elements, or that which needs selection.

Comment: Does this answer your question?